# What is the correct way to initialize an embedded Struct?

Tags: swift, swift-structs

**Scenario:** I have a struct within a Struct that is used to hold JSON data. 
**Goal:** I want to be be able to populate the sub struct via an init() for some UnitTesting work.

```
struct PortEligibility: Codable {
    var myVar = ""
    struct PortMobileNumber: Codable {
        let one: String?
        let two: String?
        let three: String?
    }
}
```

I've been toying about this but am lost:
[image]

I don't want to use a decoder. 
Remedy?

Answer (score 1):

You get the memberwise initializer if the struct base definition doesn't have any custom init methods.

```
let number = PortEligibility.PortMobileNumber(one: "one", two: "two", three: "three")
```

Also, You can either provide default value of `nil` or `""`(empty string) or specify the default value is `nil` with the struct's definition and make the empty initializer available for the struct, like this:

```
// Sample 1
let number = PortEligibility.PortMobileNumber(one: nil, two: nil, three: nil)
// or Sample 2
struct PortEligibility: Codable {
    var myVar = ""
    struct PortMobileNumber: Codable {
        var one: String? = nil
        var two: String? = nil
        var three: String? = nil
    }
}
let number = PortEligibility.PortMobileNumber()
```

Comment: Thanks.  You gave me an idea for the solution.

Comment: What's exactly the difference between these two answers? Added an `init` which is provided by the Swift compiler by default and is not required and a `getNumber` method which makes the model design shabby. Both of these methods are redundant.

Comment: This is pointless. Why would you declare your properties constants optional and assign nil to it? Those would say `nil` forever

Comment: This is merely a rough proof-of-concept; NOT production.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have the solution:

```
let number = PortEligibility.PortMobileNumber(one: "One", two: "Two", three: "Three")

struct PortEligibility: Codable {
    var myVar = ""
    struct PortMobileNumber: Codable {
        var one: String? = nil
        var two: String? = nil
        var three: String? = nil
        init(one: String?, two: String?, three: String?) {
            self.one = one
            self.two = two
            self.three = three
        }
    }

    public func getNumber() -> PortMobileNumber {
        let portMobileNuber = PortMobileNumber(one: "Hello",
                                               two: "Every",
                                               three: "Body")
        return portMobileNuber
    }
}

var portEligibility = PortEligibility()
portEligibility.myVar = "Hello World!"

print(portEligibility)
print(portEligibility.getNumber())

print(number)
```

Output:

> PortEligibility(myVar: "Hello World!") PortMobileNumber(one:
>   Optional("Hello"), two: Optional("Every"), three: Optional("Body"))
>   PortMobileNumber(one: Optional("One"), two: Optional("Two"), three:
>   Optional("Three"))